# OptaPlanner, shadow variable's corrupted value changed to uncorrupted value

Tags: optaplanner

optaplanner-bom ver 7.45.0.Final.

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Task {
    
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "timeGrainRange")
private TimeGrain startingTimeGrain;

@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = DurationUpdatingVariableListener.class,
        sources = { @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "startingTimeGrain") })
private Long durationInGrains;
......
```

in class DurationUpdatingVariableListener:

```
public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Task e) { 
    if (null == e.getStartingTimeGrain()) {
        return;
    }
    Schedule s = (Schedule)scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution();
    List<Task> tasksToBeUpdated = s.getTasksToBeUpdated(e);  // calculate all updates
    for (Task t: tasksToBeUpdated) {
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(t, NAME_DURATION);
        t.setDurationInGrains(convertToGrain(t.getDurationInSecs()));
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(t, NAME_DURATION);
    }
}
```

The logic is, when one task's startingTimeGrain changes, some tasks' duration will be affected. The problem is, when variable "tasksToBeUpdated" contains only one task, no error. When it contains more than one task, got following error:

```
ERROR 30844 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.o.c.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager   : Solving failed for problemId (1).

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The move thread with moveThreadIndex (3) has thrown an exception. Relayed here in the parent thread.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.take(OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.java:147) ~[optaplanner-core-7.45.0.Final.jar:7.45.0.Final]
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.MultiThreadedConstructionHeuristicDecider.forageResult(MultiThreadedConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:186) ~[optaplanner-core-7.45.0.Final.jar:7.45.0.Final]
    ......
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: VariableListener corruption after completedAction (Undo(id=1, ...., startingTimeGrain=null {null -> {"grainIndex":1,"id":1}})):
    The entity (id=2, ..., startingTimeGrain=1)'s shadow variable (Task.durationInGrains)'s corrupted value (4) changed to uncorrupted value (3) after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables.
      Maybe the VariableListener class (DurationUpdatingVariableListener) for that shadow variable (Task.durationInGrains) forgot to update it when one of its sources changed.

    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractScoreDirector.java:545) ~[optaplanner-core-7.45.0.Final.jar:7.45.0.Final]
    ......
```

It's sure that Task.setDurationInGrains() is only be called in the afterVariableChanged(). Why the error happens? [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vIXca63j980o9N4K9Mhv39N1N7Qhc2vM/view?usp=sharing) is the code of *Schedule.getTasksToBeUpdated(Task task)*.

Comment: Can you also show `Schedule.getTasksToBeUpdated(Task task)` body?

Comment: Append the link of the method to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your duration updating listener is able to properly "clean up" the shadow variable of all tasks that are affected by an undo move. So, for example, if you have:

```
Task(id=1, startingTimeGrain=null, durationInGrains=null)
Task(id=2, startingTimeGrain={"grainIndex":2,"id":1}, durationInGrains=3)
```

and you do

```
Move(id=1, ...., startingTimeGrain=null {null -> {"grainIndex":1,"id":1}})
```

your duration updating listener should probably result in something like:

```
Task(id=1, startingTimeGrain={"grainIndex":1,"id":1}, durationInGrains=1)
Task(id=2, startingTimeGrain={"grainIndex":2,"id":1}, durationInGrains=4)
```

Notice that Task 2 was affected by the move that changed Task 1 and its duration was updated by the listener.

If this is true, then after the move above is undone:

```
Undo(id=1, ...., startingTimeGrain=null {null -> {"grainIndex":1,"id":1}})
```

this is what absolutely must happen in order to avoid the listener corruption:

```
Task(id=1, startingTimeGrain=null, durationInGrains=null)
Task(id=2, startingTimeGrain={"grainIndex":2,"id":1}, durationInGrains=3)
```

Notice that the duration updating listener is responsible for:

1. Setting `durationInGrains` to `null` on Task 1 after the undo move unassigned it from Grain 1.
2. Recalculating duration of Task 2 that was affected by the moves on Task 1 and set its duration to the same value (3) as it was before the move on Task 1 was done.

Comment: Hint: you might also need to employ the `beforeVariableChanged()` method for the listener to be able to clean up as described above.

Comment: thank you very much Jiří, I think what you said is exactly what happens. I didn't know undo move and don't have any custom move in my code. (1) Is there any Undo Move example in the optaplanner-example project? (2) how can I tell the call to before/afterVariableChanged() is a Undo move or a normal move? so that I know when to cleanup when do not. (3) my duration calculation is somehow special, it's not serialized. In order to undo, do I need to save the shadow value before the change? It's too much work. :(

Comment: (1) Every move class is required to implement `createUndoMove()` so every move knows how to undo itself. Look for ChangeMove in optaplanner-core (built-in move type) or InvestmentQuantityTransferMove in optaplanner-examples (custom move type). (2) you shouldn't need that information. The challenge is to not only calculate the duration after a task is initialized but also to reset all shadow variables exactly to the state before a given task was initialized. Of course, without knowing whether the last move was a "do" or an "undo" move.

Comment: (3) It is possible to make the listener stateful and make it remember some information between calls but it's not recommended. Hopefully, it's not necessary in your case. If you end up taking that approach, don't forget to override `resetWorkingSolution()` and `close()`. See `VariableListener` Javadoc and https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/shadow-variable/shadow-variable.html for more information on shadow variables.